# php comparison operators 'is less than' (>) used in negative numbers is also including 0 in this switch statement?

Tags: php, switch-statement

This is the switch statement.
Only if the variable `$thumbs_number` is less than -1 (e.g. -2, -3, -4, etc.), the class `bad` should output.

But right now, the class `bad` is also being output when `$thumbs_number` is 0 (-1 and 1 have the right class: `average`).

```
<div class="topic-like-count
    <?php // Apply style based on number of votes
        switch ($thumbs_number) {
            case ($thumbs_number < -1): echo ' bad'; break;
            case ($thumbs_number == 0):
            case ($thumbs_number == 1): echo ' average'; break;
            case ($thumbs_number == 2):
            case ($thumbs_number == 3): echo ' good'; break;
            case ($thumbs_number == 4):
            case ($thumbs_number == 5): echo ' great'; break;
            case ($thumbs_number == 6):
            case ($thumbs_number == 7): echo ' excellent'; break;
            case ($thumbs_number > 7): echo ' brilliant'; break;
        }
    ?>
  ">
```

What is happening?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You a misusing the `switch` statement.

Each `case` statement compares the result of the expression to the value passed to `switch`. So here you are comparing `$thumbs_number` to the result of `($thumbs_number < -1)`, which is either `true` or `false`.

Do this instead:

```
switch ($thumbs_number) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
        echo "average";
        break;
    case 2:
    case 3:
        echo "good";
        break;
    ....
    default:
        if ($thumbs_number <= -1) echo "bad";
        else if ($thumbs_number > 7) echo "brillant";
}
```

Comment: @arnaud576875 Thanks, I had no idea about that. Is that a matter of common sense?

Comment: Yes, `switch/case` is not an alternative syntax of `if/else` statements.

Comment: Though, you could [forge a similar thing](http://data.agaric.com/how-use-less-or-greater-switch-statement).

Answer (score 3):

I faced a similar problem and I was reluctant to write a long if-else if block. Searching for an answer led me to [this page](http://data.agaric.com/how-use-less-or-greater-switch-statement).

With this technique, all you need to do is replacing

```
switch ($thumbs_number)
```

with

```
switch (true)
```

[Here](http://codepad.org/m9nwxFnK) is my version of the code: